# Printing prime numbers from an user's input php

Tags: php

I'm trying ta make a program that will ask the user for a number and then show all the prime numbers between 0 to this number in an array.

```
<?php

class SmallerPrimes{

public function __construct($file){

    $this->input_filename = $file;

}

public function Main(){

    $smaller_than = (int)$this->readString()[0];

    $result = array();        

     /* YOUR CODE HERE */          

     function isPrime($n) 
    { 
        if ($n <= 1) 

            return false; 

        for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++) 

            if ($n % $i == 0) 

                return false; 

        return true; 
    }         

    function printPrime($n) 
    { 
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++)  
        { 
            if (isPrime($i)) 

                echo $i . " "; 
        } 
    }        
    $n = 7; 

    printPrime($n);              

     /*end of your code here */       

    return $result;
}

public function readString(){

    $file = fopen($this->input_filename, "r");

    $line = array();

    while (!feof($file)){

        array_push($line, str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", fgets($file)));
    }
    return $line;
}
}

$o = new SmallerPrimes($argv[1]);
echo implode(" ", $o->Main()) . PHP_EOL;
```

This code work, but with a $n fixed.
I don't know how to use an input who ask the user a number
It's a code who verify itself and show us when it's ok

The code that i have to complete is this one (we only have this at first):

```
class SmallerPrimes{

public function __construct($file){

    $this->input_filename = $file;

}

public function Main(){

    $smaller_than = (int)$this->readString()[0];

    $result = array();

     /* YOUR CODE HERE */     

    return $result;

}

public function readString(){

    $file = fopen($this->input_filename, "r");

    $line = array();

    while (!feof($file)){

        array_push($line, str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", fgets($file)));

    }

    return $line;

    }
}

$o = new SmallerPrimes($argv[1]);

echo implode(" ", $o->Main()) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: How do you run this? Through a website?

Comment: It from a test website, i edit my question, look at the picture on the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your script:

```
<?php
class SmallerPrimes{
public function __construct($file){
    $this->input_filename = $file;
}
public function Main(){
    $smaller_than = (int)$this->readString()[0];
    $result = array();
     function isPrime($n) {
        if ($n <= 1) return false;
        for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++) if ($n % $i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
    function printPrime($n) {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++) if (isPrime($i)) $result[] = $i;
        return $result;
    }
    $result = printPrime($smaller_than);
    return $result;
}
public function readString(){
    $file = fopen($this->input_filename, "r");
    $line = array();
    while (!feof($file)){
        array_push($line, str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", fgets($file)));
    }
    return $line;
}}
$o = new SmallerPrimes($argv[1]);
echo implode(" ", $o->Main()) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it doesn't work, maybe cause i dont have a client side script.
Actually, i edit my post, and show you the complete script (it's an exercice we did in class, but the teacher didn't have the time to correct it)

Comment: Try my example. You need only php7.0-cli or php5-cli (on Linux).

Comment: I try your exemple, but the "expected output" in the exercice code said "no output".
Maybe my edit's post can help you more ?
Thanks for your help by the way !

Comment: I think that my example return your array $result.

Comment: Your method anyway is wrong, now I edit my answer so it return an array of numbers from 0 to my choice.

Comment: That's why it's so complicated, we have to keep this code.
I post the code that we need to complete in a new answer*, give a look please

Comment: What is the value of $smaller_than?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know, i just have this code, this exercice is more complicated beacause of this "first code" ...

Comment: I edit my answer with a screenshot of the exercise
Don't worry about the time, i can make this again and again

Comment: Try my example. Work like you want.

Comment: Now watch my code for understand what I have do. ;) If my answer like you please vote it and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSmallerPrimes($smaller_than) {
    if ($smaller_than <= 2) {
        return [];
    }
    $result = [2];
    $sqrt = sqrt($smaller_than);

    for ($n = 3; $n < $smaller_than; $n += 2) {
        $isPrime = true;
        foreach($result as $prime) {
            if ($n % $prime == 0) {
                $isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            if ($prime > $sqrt) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($isPrime) {
            $result[] = $n;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$input = 23;
echo implode(' ', getSmallerPrimes($input));
```

Result: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19